# Rails Photos, Users, Comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphic-associations

It's driving me crazy. I have 3 models. User, Photo, Comments.

Here is what I want to do.

A user has many photos and comments

A photo belongs to a user and has many comments

And a comment belongs to user and to a photo

So my models have these associations:

**User**

```
has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
```

**Photo**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :users, :through => :comments
has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
```

**Comment**

```
belongs_to :photo, :user
```

I want now to show a photo and load all the comments of this photo and display each comment with the user info.

**So at the photos controller show action I have**

```
@photo = Photo.find(params[:id], :include => :comments, :order => 'comments.created_at DESC')
```

**And in the photo/show view**

```
=render :partial => "/comments/partials/comment", :collection => @photo.comments, :as => :comment
```

It display the comments eg. the comment text fine but when inside the partial I try to do:

```
%p=comment.user.fname
%p=comment.body
```

It throws error "undefined method `fname' for nil:NilClass"

Something strange is that I am user authlogic so you have to be logged in to post a comment. But you can see the comments even if you are not logged in. When I am logged off it works find. When I log in it throws error.

Any help would be much appreciated cause it is driving me nuts.

By the way in my routes I have

```
map.resources :users, :has_many => [:photos, :comments]
map.resources :photos, :has_many => [:comments, :users]
```

Thanks

Comment: Verify the value of `user_id`  in `Comment` model. At `script/console` print the value of `user_id` ( i.e. ` photo.comments.each { |c| p c.user_id }` ). If any value is `nil` then there must be an error in your comments creation logic.

Comment: Thanks user_id is there at all comments. All comments in Create method take the current_user.id as user_id since I am using authlogic and you have to be logged in to add a comment.

Comment: A strange thing is that if I try to do comment.photo.id it finds it fine I can get the photo where the comment belongs to. When I do comment.user.id though it returns nil but only when a user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will make a difference, but have you tried separating the belongs_to associations?

```
belongs_to :photo
belongs_to :user
```

Comment: Thanks this is not the problem definitely

Answer (score 0):

+1 for using haml

i can think of a few reasons why this might happen

firstly, what happens when your remove the following line from your code?

```
# try removing this
%p=comment.user.fname
```

Does the error then move on to next variable (i.e. comment.body)

If not, then you have at least narrowed it down to the fname variable.  in which case I would wonder if you have perhaps added the fname variable to your model after creating some intitial database entries...  this would mean that some of hte entries don't have associated fname variables.  in this instance you can fix the issue by scrubbing the database and remigrating from scratch

Also, do you have attr_accessible set for the fname variable in your model?  chekc that you have this set for all the variables.

can you look inside your db and make sure that all entries have an fname variable set?

I realise that you want to get this working but if you can't, there's no shame in using the disqus.com plugin - it saves you db space, helps to attract more comments as lots of people already have profiles and gives you some nifty moderator features...  on the downside, you lose branding, and you can't use any of your own rjs effects..

good luck

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the answer

The problem comes when I try to retrieve the user from the comment. When I call the photo from the comment it works.

The database is clean there are no records in and the issue exists but only when I am logged in. I think there is some kind of mix up between authlogic and my models.